# remove duplicate element from a list, but only those who has odd number of duplicates

Tags: python, list

I am trying remove duplicate elements from the list, whose number of duplicates is odd.
For example for the following list: `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 8, 1, 8]` I have 1 duplicated 2 times, 3 duplicated 3 times, and 8 duplicated 2 times. So 1 and 8 should be out and instead of 3 elements of 3 I need to leave only 1.

This is what I came up with:

```
def remove_odd_duplicates(arr):
    h = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i in h:
            h[i] += 1
        else:
            h[i] = 1

    arr = []
    for i in h:
        if h[i] % 2:
            arr.append(i)

    return arr
```

It returns everything correctly: `[2, 3, 5]`, but I do believe that this can be written in a nicer way. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the order matters?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary the order does not matter, but the complexity is. In my case it is O(n) and I do not want it to deteriorate to O(n^2) with counting elements

Comment: @SalvadorDali this kind of algorithm is more like n log n because of repeated look ups. the linear scan at the end is not significant, asymtopically.

Comment: @user3125280 Dicts in Python have `O(1)` lookup, so it is `O(N)`.

Comment: @SalvadorDali if you want to remove only odd duplicates then why the even duplicates got removed also?

Comment: @AvinashRaj even duplicates are not removed. They are just substituted for the one element. So if I have 5 elements 2, then I need to keep only 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and list comprehension, like this

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 8, 1, 8]
from collections import Counter
print [item for item, count in Counter(data).items() if count % 2]
# [2, 3, 5]
```

The `Counter` gives a dictionary, with every element in the input iterable as the keys and their corresponding counts as the values. So, we iterate over that dict and check if the count is odd and filter only those items out.

**Note:** The complexity of this solution is still O(N), just like your original program.

Comment: are you sure it is still O(n)? Because when I was thinking about this solution I viewed it as O(n^2) due to the fact that for each of element I need to calculate the number of such elements. And the way it is done is by iterating the list for the second time, thus exploding to O(n^2).

Comment: @SalvadorDali You can think of `Counter` as an abstraction of what you have done in your solution with the dictionary, so it is still O(N) :-)

Answer (score 2):

If order doesn't matter:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 8, 1, 8]
>>> list(set([x for x in a if a.count(x)%2 == 1]))
[2, 3, 5]
```

The list comprehension `[x for x in a if a.count(x)%2 == 1]` returns only the elements which appear an odd number of times in the list. `list(set(...))` is a common way of removing duplicate entries from a  list.

Comment: Concise but `O(N**2)` in complexity.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly less efficient than the other answer here (I've just noticed in the comments above that the OP would prefer `O(N)` solutions).

Answer (score 1):

you can possibly use [`scipy.stats.itemfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html):

```
>>> from scipy.stats import itemfreq
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 8, 1, 8]
>>> ifreq = itemfreq(xs)
>>> ifreq
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 3],
       [5, 1],
       [8, 2]])
>>> i = ifreq[:, 1] % 2 != 0
>>> ifreq[i, 0]
array([2, 3, 5])
```